# Define a custom function in a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a programming language with Python. I want to be able to run functions by typing:

```
task $function:
    log "Hey!"
```

and then you can call it by typing:

```
$function
```

Right now, I have this code:

```
def runFunction(self, f):
    ## Here's where I need help. How will you make a function that runs a function that doesn't exist in 
    ## the code?
...

elif i == 'task':
    self.string = line[5:]
    self.output = self.string.replace('{', '')
    self.function = self.output.replace('}', '')
...

elif i not in self.keywords and '$' in i:
    if i == self.function:
        self.runFunction(self.function)
```

What should I do to make a `runFunction()` function?

Comment: I'm not quite following what exactly you need help with. Do you have trouble *defining* a function (the first code block) or *executing* a function (the second code block)? Your question implies the latter, yet if you already do manage the first part, then by definition you have a function that you can execute.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi actually i have trouble with both. I need to be able to define functions, and executing them. Sorry for being vague, I've only been programming for a few months.

Comment: If you are looking for help on how to translate the code in the first place, we must know what the code means – i.e. how the language is defined. If you are new to programming, you probably lack a lot of experience on programming languages themselves in general; you may want to start with simpler languages, e.g. [algebraic ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63030278/parsing-pseudo-algebraic-string-into-command) first.

Comment: No, I know Python. I'm just experimenting and going out of my comfort zone to experiment and maybe expand my knowledge. I can make apps with Python, and I know how to use tkinter too. It's just that im experimenting.

Comment: If you want to support recursion, scoped vars, types etc. you really need to learn some basics of programming language design, like @MisterMiyagi mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What you could do?

You could use python built in function called  **eval()** which lets you evaluate expressions dynamically.

### Solution

```
def runFunction(self, f):
    eval(f)
```

> Where f has to be a string

### And if you want to create functions:

You could use exec() which can evaluate a string.

Demonstration:

```
exec("def myFunction(a,b): return a + b")
```

and use it like

```
eval("myFunction(1,2)")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One problem tho, I need to be able to define a function too. First, you need to define a function and then you'll be able to execute this.

Comment: I have just edited the answer. With the exec() python built in function you can create functions. If my answer  has been useful and solved your question, please don't forget to mark it as correct. @ineedhelp