# How to find the parentheses and calculate the percentage of elements in a chemical composition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, parsing, parentheses

Hi I am trying to get the percentage of each element from a chemical composition. The following code works well for normal chemical compositions.

```
comp = "Ag20Al25La55"

re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]?)([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*)', comp)
```

output is

```
[('Ag', '20'), ('Al', '25'), ('La', '55')]
```

Bur how can I get something similar with the parentheses?

```
comp = "(Cu60Zr40)98Y2"
```

The above code would give

```
[('Cu', '60'), ('Zr', '40'), ('Y', '2')]
```

But the correct output should be

```
[('Cu', '58.8'), ('Zr', '39.2'), ('Y', '2')]
```

Because we have to multiply 98 by 60% to get the percentage for Cu and multiply 98 by 40% to get the percentage for Zr.

Comment: Please do not just give *some* examples, but provide a definition of your grammar. Very importantly, clarify whether it can be recursive/nested – e.g. is ``((Cu60)98Zr40)98`` also a valid expression?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing pseudo-algebraic string into command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63030278/parsing-pseudo-algebraic-string-into-command)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No ((Cu60)98Zr40)98 would not be a valid expression. I give this example because other cases will look exactly the same as this one. No nested cases. Only a pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
def compute(x):
  y = float(x.group(2))
  return ''.join([i+str(float(j)*y/100) for i,j in re.findall('([A-z]+)(\\d+[.]?\\d*)', x.group(1))])
  
def final(x): 
    cmp = re.sub('(\\(.*\\))(\\d+)', compute, x)
    return re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]?)([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*)', cmp)

final(comp)
[('Cu', '58.8'), ('Zr', '39.2'), ('Y', '2')]
```

Disclaimer: Not the best way to do this

Comment: @HumanLearning if this works, you could acept the answer to close the question