# python calculating parsed logical expression (without eval)

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I'm looking for the best way of calculating a string expression that holds a logical expression like: `x and not y or (z or w)` or a json logic like: `{"and": {"x": "true", "y": "false"}, "or": {"or": {"z": "true", "w": "True"}}}`

I decide how to config file should look like so the format could be changed, it's just an example.

I saw a way to parse the first string using `pyparse` to something like: `['x', 'AND', 'y', 'OR', ['z', 'OR', 'W']]` but I don't know how to get the value of the expression after I parsed it.

About the json logic format I saw the package `json-logic` tried it but it seems like the code is broken since I can't run any of their examples so if there is something else I think that would be great.

```
x = True
y = False
z = False
w = False
calc_string_as_bool('x and not y or (z or w)') -> True
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you provide expected outputs? I don't understand what you're after.

Comment: @theherk added the expected output

Comment: you need to evaluate your expression. If you don't want to use `eval` provided by python you create your own token extractor and evaluator. It will convert your expression into a tree based on operation's priorities and then evaluate it by resolving the tree.

Comment: If you don't want to use eval, you may look into `operator` module. There you can find `and_`, `or_`... that you can use when you find right word in your expression

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing pseudo-algebraic string into command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63030278/parsing-pseudo-algebraic-string-into-command)

Comment: See if this example in the pyparsing repo gives you any leads: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/simpleBool.py  The example includes code for both parsing and evaluating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Python's parser but not its evaluator, you can do that. You'll have to evaluate the expression yourself, but if you only need to handle boolean expressions, that won't be too difficult. In any event, it's a reasonable way to learn how to write an evaluator without having to worry about parsing.

To parse an expression, you can use `ast.parse` with `mode='eval'`; that will return a AST without evaluating anything.

Evaluating an AST is generally done with a depth-first scan, which is easy enough to write, but the ast module comes with the `NodeVisitor` class which takes care of some of the details. You need to create your own subclass of `NodeVisitor` in which you define methods named `visit_X` for each AST node type X. These methods can return results, so typically an evaluator will just define a visitor method for the particular AST node types which can be evaluated; these method will evaluate each child node using the subclass's `visit` method, combine the values as appropriate, and return the result.

That was probably not very clear, so I'll put an an example below.

***Important***: the AST nodes are all documented in [Python's library reference manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#node-classes). You'll need to refer to that document constantly while you're writing your evaluator. Make sure that you are using the version of the documentation which corresponds to your Python version, since the AST structure does change from time to time.

Here's a simple evaluator (honest! it's mostly comments) which handles the boolean operators `and`, `if` and `not`. It handles variables by looking their names up in a dictionary (which must be provided when you construct the evaluator object), and it knows about constant values. Anything it doesn't understand causes it to raise an exception, and I tried to be fairly strict.

```py
import ast
class BooleanEvaluator(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, symtab = None):
        '''Create a new Boolean Evaluator.
           If you want to allow named variables, give the constructor a
           dictionary which maps names to values. Any name not in the 
           dictionary will provoke a NameError exception, but you could
           use a defaultdict to provide a default value (probably False).
           You can modify the symbol table after the evaluator is
           constructed, if you want to evaluate an expression with different
           values.
        '''
        self.symtab = {} if symtab is None else symtab

    # Expression is the top-level AST node if you specify mode='eval'.
    # That's not made very clear in the documentation. It's different
    # from an Expr node, which represents an expression statement (and
    # there are no statements in a tree produced with mode='eval').
    def visit_Expression(self, node):
        return self.visit(node.body)

    # 'and' and 'or' are BoolOp, and the parser collapses a sequence of
    # the same operator into a single AST node. The class of the .op
    # member identifies the operator, and the .values member is a list 
    # of expressions.
    def visit_BoolOp(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.op, ast.And):
            return all(self.visit(c) for c in node.values)
        elif isinstance(node.op, ast.Or):
            return any(self.visit(c) for c in node.values)
        else:
            # This "shouldn't happen".
            raise NotImplementedError(node.op.__doc__ + " Operator")

    # 'not' is a UnaryOp. So are a number of other things, like unary '-'.
    def visit_UnaryOp(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.op, ast.Not):
             return not self.visit(node.operand)
        else:
            # This error can happen. Try using the `~` operator.
            raise NotImplementedError(node.op.__doc__ + " Operator")

    # Name is a variable name. Technically, we probably should check the
    # ctx member, but unless you decide to handle the walrus operator you
    # should never see anything other than `ast.Load()` as ctx.
    # I didn't check that the symbol table contains a boolean value,
    # but you could certainly do that.
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        try:
            return self.symtab[node.id]
        except KeyError:
            raise NameError(node.id)

    # The only constants we're really interested in are True and False,
    # but you could extend this to handle other values like 0 and 1
    # if you wanted to be more liberal
    def visit_Constant(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.value, bool):
            return node.value
        else:
            # I avoid calling str on the value in case that executes
            # a dunder method.
            raise ValueError("non-boolean value")

    # The `generic_visit` method is called for any AST node for
    # which a specific visitor method hasn't been provided.
    def generic_visit(self, node):
        raise RuntimeError("non-boolean expression")
```

Here's a sample of how to use the evaluator. This function takes an expression which uses exactly three variables, which must be named x, y and z, and produces a truth table.

```py
import itertools
def truthTable(expr):
    evaluator = BooleanEvaluator()
    theAST = ast.parse(expr, mode='eval')
    print("x  y  z  " + expr) 
    for x, y, z in itertools.product([True, False], repeat=3):
        evaluator.symtab = {'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z}
        print('  '.join("FT"[b] for b in (x, y, z, evaluator.visit(theAST))))

truthTable('x and (y or not z) and (not y or z)')
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the very detailed answer! I still need to really get into it to understand it but from the tests I ran its working and exactly what I looked for.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds to me like what you're after **is** [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), even though you say without eval.

```
In [1]: True and True
Out[1]: True

In [2]: e = "True and True"

In [3]: eval(e)
Out[3]: True

In [4]: el = ["True", "and", "True"]

In [5]: eval(" ".join(el))
Out[5]: True
```

Maybe you can clarify why using eval to do what eval does isn't an option.

---

Adding example, based on sample in question:

```py
def eval_recurse(ops, replacements):
    evaluated = []
    for op in ops:
        if type(op) is list:
            evaluated.append(str(eval_recurse(op, replacements)))
            continue
        if str(op).lower() in ["and", "not", "or"]:
            op = op.lower()
        if op in replacements:
            op = str(replacements[op])
        evaluated.append(op)
    return eval(" ".join(evaluated))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    replacements = {"x": True, "y": False, "z": False, "w": False}
    print(eval_recurse(["x", "AND", "NOT", "y", "OR", ["z", "OR", "w"]], replacements))
```

This yields `True`. This may not be helpful since you don't want to use eval, but I figured I'd provide it in case.

Comment: the title literally said without eval

Comment: Eval is just not that good to use in python on a large scale project: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: If it isn't clear why the specified border condition is relevant, a solution to the problem given in the question can be given. We can find information about this in meta. I assure my effort was to be helpful. It wasn't specified why eval was out of the question.

Comment: @EmaIl if you don't use eval because it's dangerous then use `ast.literal_eval` which safetely evaluates the expressions  https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: @XxJames07- see [The XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/313590)

Comment: tried literal eval got this error:
`ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Compare object at 0x7f80c8f15bb0>`
also `True and True` isn't going to help me, I'm looking for a way to use variables values that could change

Comment: Yes, that was just to illustrate that you can join together string components of your expression. That could be a formatted string where you replace the operations with the contents of your variables.

Comment: @EmaIl: I have added a sample function, knowing it may not be useful given your constraints.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` won't work here, since `x`, `y`, and `z` are not literals.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` also won't evaluate `True or True` or `6+11`, since those are expressions, not literals.